# How to view a full rendered 3D model on a HTML document

Tags: html, blender, x3dom

I'm currently developing a web application that allow users to view a 3D model so they can view the details of a item, I manage to do this by creating a x3D file on Blender and insert it into a HTML via X3DOM library. now i would like to put a fully rendered 3D model and put some animation is this possible?

My current 3D model

[Current 3D model](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eJVFO.jpg)

What i want to achieve

[Full rendered 3D model](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OMJoB.jpg)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, X3DOM supports animations:

http://doc.x3dom.org/tutorials/animationInteraction/animate/index.html